# How to query for parent package in bazel

Tags: bazel

Say I have the following bazel workspace:

```
   - WORKSPACE
   - BUILD.bazel
   + [sub-a]
    | - BUILD.bazel
    | - MANIFEST.MF
    | + [sub-b]
       | - BUILD.bazel
```

Which `bazel query` command can I write to package `//sub-a` from packge `//sub-a/sub-b`? (The next parent package).

Comment: Each package is independent from each other. Whether a package is physically within another package doesn't make a difference.

But maybe you can clarify what you want to do?

Comment: Trying to reach from filepath to co-responding `java_library` target, this target may exist in the same package as the label of the file or in a package above it... Since `bazel query "attr('srcs', {label}, {package})"` requires package scope, I'm trying it find it recursively, each time on the next parent package

Comment: If you have a path, you just need to look for the first directory that contains a `BUILD.bazel` file.
This command may help: `bazel query src/main/java/com/example/Example.java`
It will convert the file to a label (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any easy way to do this, but you may find [`rdeps`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#rdeps) helpful.